# Can I rely on Cheerio to return items in document order?

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I'm using cheerio.js for web scraping. It has shown to have subtle differences from jquery, for example, `:eq` is not available in selector. I'd like to ask from experience whether I can trust `cheerio` to return items in document order. For example, if I have a `<ul><li></li><li></li></ul>` and I run `$('li').get(0)`, it will give me the first list item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a web scraper a few days ago with cheerio and request. Also i used cheerio in other projects in order to make dynamic email content. It always has respected the order of the matched elements in the DOM. You can use the :nth-child pseudo-selector too.